# missing terminating > character at line 17

Tags: c

Gcc compiler gives error at line 17

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a[8]={4,9,15,20};
    int b[4]={3,5,10,13};
    int i,j,n=3;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(b[i]<a[i])
        {
            for(j=n;j>=i;j--)
            {
                a[j+1]=a[j];
            }
        a[i]=b[i];
        n=n+1;
        } 
        else
        {
            for(j=n;j>=i;j--)
            {
                a[j+1]=a[j];
            }
        a[i+1]=b[i];
        n++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    printf(" %d", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Which is line 17, what error does it give?

Comment: missing terminating > character

Comment: then why you are correcting error ?? There is no such error in you code I could find :)

Comment: BTW: main() shall return int. `void main()` works for Herb Schildt only.

Comment: Also, I'm not getting any errors from the code above. The only (syntactic) problem I can see is the return type from main, which is `int`, not `void`.

Comment: @avakar: in you edit, you added the missing `<stdio.h>`. Update: mo it was filterd by the CMS (as a html-tag).

Comment: i am unable to track where i am missing > character

Comment: @wildplasser, I didn't, it got consumed as a HTML tag.

Comment: Guys I missed that in <stdio.h>

Comment: @user2279443, copy-paste the exact error message into the question and mark the offending line with a comment.

Comment: But on running the program i get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @avakar the error is debugged but on running the code I get a segmentation fault

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan I am getting a segmentation fault on running the program. Plzz help sir!!

Comment: because out of index buffer overrun, not sure let me check ..

Comment: what change should i make to get it resolved?

Comment: @user2279443 see its your code working below//

Comment: @user2279443 Refactoring could help. Take the most repetitive part of your code, and put it in a function. Use that function in place of that code in main. In this case, your inner-most loops already have a standardised, refactored alternative: `memmove(a + j + 1, a + j, j - i);` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are code gives segmentation fault because you are accessing memory after array index size.

To debug it I simply added two likes in you code to print `n, i , j`:

```
if(b[i]<a[i])
{
    for(j=n;j>=i;j--)
    {
        a[j+1]=a[j];
    }
    a[i]=b[i];
    n = n+1;            "<---- 1 Correction need here"
    printf("In IF %d %d %d\n", i, j, n);
} 
else
{
    for(j=n;j>=i;j--)
    {
        a[j+1]=a[j];
    }
    a[i+1]=b[i];
    n++;              "<----2 Correction need here"   
    printf("In Else %d %d %d\n", i, j, n);
}
```

its output is:

```
$ ./a.out 
In IF 0 -1 4
In Else 1 0 5
In Else 2 1 6
In Else 3 2 7
In Else 4 3 8     
In IF 5 4 9      
In IF 6 5 10        <--  i, j, n    "buffer overflow"
In IF 7 6 11        <--  i, j, n  
In IF 8 7 12        <--  i, j, n
In IF 20 11 13      <--  i, j, n
 3 4 5 10 13 5 5 10
```

Suggestion don't change  `n` in your loop change you logic on this

Comment: the problem is to merge the sorted arrays a and b into a in sorted order.